# Asymptotic Expansion of Integrals in general form

Tags: asymptotics

How to understand asymptotic expansion of 
$$ I(s) = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+s f(x)}}$$
where $f$ is periodic of period 1, $f(x) \geq 0$ as $s\longrightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 0):

**just a small hint**

Let $$J (s)=I (\frac {1}{s}) $$

$$=\int_0^1\sqrt {\frac{s}{f (x)}}\frac {dx}{(1+\frac{s}{f (x)})^\frac12} $$

use that near $t=0$,

$$(1+t)^\frac12=1+\frac {t}{2}+... $$